# I have a single entry Schengen visa from Spain

Tags: visas, schengen

I have a single entry Schengen visa from spain, do I have to go to spain or is it valid to use in for instance France?

Comment: wait, do you mean to enter in Paris or to go from Spain to Paris?

Comment: The way it reads is going to France instead of Spain...